# Introducing new black and white oscillaris to 5 yr old oscillaris that lost mate possible?

Tags: fish

150 gal fish and reef tank. One ascillaris died 8 mos ago. Paired for over 5 yrs. Is it possible to introduce a younger one? I have many rose anemonies.[image: enter image description here]![enter image description here]